# Column value incremental update

Tags: r, data.table

Fellow R-Stackoverflowers,

I have a data table with 2 columns and I'm trying to calculate a new third column based on both the 2 existing column values and the new column calculated value for the previous row.

I have been checking the forums and I have tried a couple of answers but I don't get it right. I hope you can help me.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
error <- c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
trigger <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
expected <- c(1,2,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0)
DTtest <- data.table(error, trigger, expected)
DTtest
     error trigger expected 
 1:     1   FALSE        1     
 2:     1    TRUE        2     
 3:     0   FALSE        0     
 4:     0   FALSE        0     
 5:     0   FALSE        0     
 6:     1   FALSE        1     
 7:     1    TRUE        2     
 8:     1    TRUE        3     
 9:     1    TRUE        4     
10:     0   FALSE        0
```

The "expected" column includes the values I expect to calculate with the "error" and "trigger" columns. The formula I would like to apply would be the following:

```
if(trigger) {
    new_column = new_column(previous_row) + 1
} else {
    new_column = error
}
```

My first try was to use an ifelse directly to update the new column. I found that I had to actually initialize the new column for it to run:

```
DTtest <- DTtest[, impact:=0]
DTtest[, impact:=ifelse(trigger, lag(impact)+1, error)]
```

This option does calculate the new column "impact" but the results do not match the expected value I got calculating the column in Excel (something I can't do with the whole data table, as it's pretty big):

```
    error trigger expected impact
 1:     1   FALSE        1      1
 2:     1    TRUE        2      1
 3:     0   FALSE        0      0
 4:     0   FALSE        0      0
 5:     0   FALSE        0      0
 6:     1   FALSE        1      1
 7:     1    TRUE        2      1
 8:     1    TRUE        3      1
 9:     1    TRUE        4      1
10:     0   FALSE        0      0
```

Then I tried a for loop but the results are not correct either:

```
for(index in nrow(DTtest)){
  imp <- 0
  if(index==1){
    imp <- DTtest[index]$error
  } else {
    imp <- DTtest[index-1]$impact+1
  }
  set(DTtest, i=index, j=as.integer(4), value=imp )
}
```

I have the feeling that lag(impact) does not get the updated value for some reason, but I can't fancy why.

Would you please help me? .

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach using groups:

```
DTtest[, grp:=cumsum(!trigger)][,new:=c(error[1], cumsum(head(error, -1))+1),grp][]

    error trigger expected grp new
 1:     1   FALSE        1   1   1
 2:     1    TRUE        2   1   2
 3:     0   FALSE        0   2   0
 4:     0   FALSE        0   3   0
 5:     0   FALSE        0   4   0
 6:     1   FALSE        1   5   1
 7:     1    TRUE        2   5   2
 8:     1    TRUE        3   5   3
 9:     1    TRUE        4   5   4
10:     0   FALSE        0   6   0
```

Answer (score 3):

This can probably be code golfed, but I like my code verbose:

```
DTtest[, impact := error]

#add a TRUE before each trigger run
DTtest[, trigger1 := trigger | shift(trigger, 1L, fill = FALSE, type = "lead")]

#IDs for by
DTtest[, rleid := rleid(trigger1)]

#cumsum by
DTtest[(trigger1), impact := cumsum(impact), by = rleid]

#    error trigger expected impact trigger1 rleid
# 1:     1   FALSE        1      1     TRUE     1
# 2:     1    TRUE        2      2     TRUE     1
# 3:     0   FALSE        0      0    FALSE     2
# 4:     0   FALSE        0      0    FALSE     2
# 5:     0   FALSE        0      0    FALSE     2
# 6:     1   FALSE        1      1     TRUE     3
# 7:     1    TRUE        2      2     TRUE     3
# 8:     1    TRUE        3      3     TRUE     3
# 9:     1    TRUE        4      4     TRUE     3
#10:     0   FALSE        0      0    FALSE     4
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the cumsum but it does not give me the expected values. I'd like to cumsum just for the error>0 groups (group of error=1 values between error=0 values), I don't know if that's possible

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Create new "dummy" column that copy the error when trigger == TRUE

```
DTtest[DTtest$trigger=="TRUE", "dummy"]<- DTtest[DTtest$trigger=="TRUE", "error"]
DTtest[is.na(DTtest$dummy), "dummy"] <- 0 # replace NA in dummy column with 0
```

Loop based on dummy column:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(DTtest)){
  if(i == 1)DTtest[i, "new"] <- 0
  else DTtest[i, "new"] <- DTtest[i,"dummy"] + DTtest[i-1,"new"]
} 

   error trigger expected dummy new
1      1   FALSE        1     0   0
2      1    TRUE        2     1   1
3      0   FALSE        0     0   1
4      0   FALSE        0     0   1
5      0   FALSE        0     0   1
6      1   FALSE        1     0   1
7      1    TRUE        2     1   2
8      1    TRUE        3     1   3
9      1    TRUE        4     1   4
10     0   FALSE        0     0   4
```

Comment: This obviously doesn't match the "expected" column (and besides is not using data.table "coding style")

Comment: Yep, it gets closer but the new values are not the expected values. I'm trying to figure something out with the dummy column, though.